# Replace semicolon with other character in sql export phpmyadmin

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, export, mariadb

I want to change a query separator `;` to any other character in phpmyadmin with maria db server.

I dont see any options for this.

any help?

Comment: Are you talking about exported SQL ? Why do you want to change ?

Comment: i want to separate all query with separator (using explode of php), but my query has a semicolon inside so it generates wrong data.

Comment: how are you doing the explode? copying all the sql data and making it a string?

Comment: file_get_content() of php

Comment: Sounds like you need "enclosed by".

Comment: is enclosed by gives me a queries like sql export?